# How to get count from table and set as a text on textview in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i am new to android and getting total number of rows from SQlite table and set it as a text to a textview. i  have searched it alot read many related posts but unfortunately can't succeed with it anybody helped me plzzz...

Here is my Query

```
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  Tasks ", null);
         int x = cur.getCount();
            cur.close();
            return x;
```

my java code is

```
TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcount);
       count.setText(String.valueOf(myAdapter.GetTasksCount()));
```

thanks in advance

Comment: post your full db code...

Comment: The get count() Call return the number of rows returned and not the result you are looking for. you need to iterate the cursor and find the result which is probably in col 1 row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Approach (haven't checked it) -

```
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(" SELECT Count(*) FROM  Tasks ", null);
int x = 0;
if (cur.moveToFirst())
{
    x = cur.getInt(0);
}
cur.close();
return x;
```

Comment: how can i set it to a textview in a listview item

Comment: you will have to create a special item in your adapter for that. i would suggest using a seperate view (not in the listview) for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    myAdapter.openToRead();
    int i = myAdapter.GetTasksCount();
    TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcount);
   count.setText(Integer.toString(i));
```

Comment: have you get the count from adapter?

Comment: sir i have try this it works fine it show 1 but i want to show all row number

Comment: yah there are 4 rows in table